# Fetching User credentials in UI5 application dynamically for External services

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

Currently we have requirement to develop a custom Fiori App using external Restful Web services. I am able to get the data from the back end using basic authentication. Kindly find the below image for details. I have hard coded one of our back end user credentials in the image below.

[Working code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhfM0.png)

Our back end is having only this basic authentication option to fetch the data. We have only this possibility to fetch back end data. Currently it is working fine with single user credentials. Now my requirement is that i will deploy this app in the front end server. We will be using Single sign on option for our implementation in Front end server. So front end credentials will be same as back end credentials.

After the user logged in from Fiori Client in the mobile. Is there any option to fetch the user credentials in the Java script from the current user session or from cookies so that i consume our back-end Restful service using the dynamic approach.

Please help me out.

Regards
Phani Poorna

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned scenario might be possible if SingleSignOn is also configured for the backend.
Otherwise, we don’t see a possibility to get the SSO user credentials via Javascript from the current user session nor from cookies.

Comment: Hi single sign on is enabled for backend as well for my scenrio. How how to get user id and password dynamically? Kidnly share code snippet